# Creating Command Buttons in Visual Basic Editor to Write Code Blocks

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to help some people in my office learn some very basic VBA. I think it would be hugely helpful to create some command buttons for the VBE toolbar that insert common pieces of code I write, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

I know that I can create .txt files and insert those, but I'm trying to make it as easy as possible.

Any help is appreciated, and thank you in advance!

Comment: That is outside of the scope of VBA. You're talking about something more along the lines of writing an Add-In for the editor. You would be better off creating a code module that your users can import, but even then I suspect you're going to have issues. The better approach would be to teach them how to use the macro-recorder, and help them refine the code from there, or even better, work on developing a code base of sorts where you have classes that can be easily reused for your different projects.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I understand I would need to write it as an add-in and I'm willing to. The record macro button unfortunately won't do much as most of what I'm thinking about is dynamic (i.e. last_row, arrays, regexp)

Comment: https://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012013.aspx